# How can I print the required row when reading a csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am a beginner of python, I have an assignment that wants me to read a csv file and print out the related information.

I have an excel file which includes student's ID, school and hobby.

now I want to write a program to show the detail of the student by entering the ID.
requirements are:

1. print the entire row when ID is correctly input
2. print "Empty, try again" when ID input is space
3. print "No record" when the input is invalid or there is no matching record

I manage to fulfill the first 2 requirements but have no idea how to get the third. Seems like my code is always looping through each of the data and print "No record"  every time, i.e. if there are 3 records, 3 "No record" will be printed. Could someone help me with it? Much thanks! Below will be my code.

```
import csv
file = "a.csv"

sID = input("Enter ID: ")

while (sID == " "):
    print("Empty input,enter again")
    sID = input("Enter ID: ")

with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (sID == row["id"]):
            print("{0}{1}{2}".format(row[id],row[school],row[hobby])
        else:
            print("No record")
```

Comment: I know it shouldn't be difficult, my hint is to use a counter to determine if no record is found. But I cannot figure it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a few changes:

- You should use the `str.strip()` method to test if a string is empty so that it accounts for any number of spaces.
- You should quote the column names to make them string literals when using them as indices to access the value of a column in the current row.
- You should use the optional [`else`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) block for your `for` loop to determine that there is no matching record found, and `break` the loop if there is one found.
- You are missing a right parenthesis for the `print` call that outputs a row.

With the above changes, your code should look like:

```
import csv
file = "a.csv"

sID = input("Enter ID: ")

while not sID.strip():
    print("Empty input,enter again")
    sID = input("Enter ID: ")

with open(file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (sID == row["id"]):
            print("{0}{1}{2}".format(row['id'],row['school'],row['hobby']))
            break
    else:
        print("No record")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation. The problem is solved!